# How to calculate line integral using Green's theorem

Tags: integration, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I had this specific task in my math exam and didn't solve it correctly. Also, I, unfortunately, don't have any correct result. So I am asking you, if anyone can solve and explain it to me. I would be super grateful. Sorry for my bad English, it's my second language.

Calculate the line integral where *l* is upper section of circle $$x^2+y^2=16x$$ form point A(16,0) to point B(0,0)

$$\int_l (e^xsiny-7y) dx + (e^xcosy-7)dy$$

I tried doing this :
First, I wrote circle like this:
$$ x^2−16x+y^2=0,(x−2\sqrt{2})^2+y^2=2\sqrt{2} $$
Then, I wrote that
$$ P=e^xsiny−7y $$
and
$$ Q=e^xcosy−7 $$

After that I calculated derivatives $$ \frac{dP}{dy} $$  and $$ \frac{dQ}{dx} $$ , put them back in double integral, using Green's theorem.
Meaning I did the following:
$\iint_D (\frac{dQ}{dx}  - \frac{dP}{dy})\,dx\,dy$

I used the points A and B to define the boundaries, but failed when I got zero as an result.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. It would be great if you could add your attempt to the post! Also, no need to apologize, your English is fine :)

Comment: Do not worry about being wrong. What is important is that you want to learn.

Comment: Please add this to your original post, the comments can otherwise become a bit a messy and the post hard to follow if anyone else searches this question.

Comment: @AndréArmatowski oh, I will. I am new to this, kinda struggling, but thank you so much for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idéa! Greens theorem states the if $l$ is a closed curve oriented counter clockwise and $D$ is the area which $l$ encloses then
$$\int_{l}P\,dx+Q\,dy=\iint_{D}\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\,dx\,dy.$$
In your case the simple closed line $l$ is the $x$-axis and the part of the circle $x^{2}+y^{2}=16x$ which lies above the $x$-axis. We also have $P=e^{x}\sin(y)-7y$ and $Q=e^{x}\cos(y)-7$.

We then calculate the partial derivatives:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} &= e^{x}\cos(y) \\
&\text{and}\\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} &= e^{x}\cos(y)-7\end{align*}
and therefore
$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=e^{x}\cos(y)-(e^{x}\cos(y)-7)=7.$$
This is really nice since
\begin{align*}\int_{l}(e^{x}\sin(y)-7y)\,dx+(e^{x}\cos(y)-7)\,dy &=\iint_{D}7\,dx\,dy\\
&= 7\times \text{Area}(D).\end{align*}

We can re-write the circles equation as
$$(x-8)^{2}+y^{2}=8^{2}$$
which is a circle with middle point $(8,0)$ and radius $8$. This means that $D$ is precisely the half disc that is part of this circle and lies above the $x$-axis. Therefore the area of $D$ is $$\frac{1}{2}(8^{2}\pi)$$
so the answer is
$$7\times 32\times\pi= 224\pi$$